# Colocar una imagen esquina superior izquierda formulario CSS

Tags: css, padding, margin

Tengo un **formulario** al cual tiene como propiedad **id="miformulario"**, en el cual pido los datos para acceder a una página web.

Quiero que aparezca en este **formulario** en la esquina superior izquierda un **icono/imagen**.

> ¿Qué propiedades debo utilizar, además de **margin** y **padding**? ¿Se puede agregar la imagen desde `CSS` o hay que incluirla en el `HTML` con ***<.img src="..." .../>***

*Imaginad que la imagen se llama "imagenes/prueba.jpg" con un tamaño **height=12** y **width=12***

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 /*background: #DEDEDE;*/
 display: flex; /*Centrado en la página tanto vertical como horizontal.*/
 min-height: 100vh;
 /*background-size: cover;*/
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}

form{
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
 max-width: 500px;
 background: #F3F3F3;
 padding: 30px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}

h2{
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

h4{
 text-align: center;
}

input{
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 30px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
 background: linear-gradient(#FFDA63, #FFB940);
 border: 0;
 width: 160px;
 color: brown;
 opacity: 0.8;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-link{
 font-size: 14px;
}


a:hover  {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Formulario de Login - Cliente</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_iniciar_sesion.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo2.jpg">
  <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
   <h2>CLIENTE</h2>
   <h4>INICIAR SESIÓN</h4>
   <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1">
   <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2">
   <div id="mensaje" align="center">
                <?php if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'true'): ?>
                    <h4><p style="color:red;">¡Sus datos no son correctos!</p></h4>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
   <div id="iniciar" align="center">
    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"><br/>
    <p class="form-link">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? <a href="registrar.php">Regístrate aquí</a></p><br/>
    <p class="form-link"><a href="recuperar_contrasena.php">He olvidado mi contraseña</a></p><br/><hr/><br/>
    <p class="form-link"><img src="imagenes/entrar.jpg" height="10px" width="10px" alt="invitado"/>&nbsp;<a href="reservar.php">Entrar como invitado</a></p>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los estilos en linea en la imagen los puedes poner en el css, esto solo es un ejemplo.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  /*background: #DEDEDE;*/
  display: flex;
  /*Centrado en la página tanto vertical como horizontal.*/
  min-height: 100vh;
  /*background-size: cover;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #F3F3F3;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background: linear-gradient(#FFDA63, #FFB940);
  border: 0;
  width: 160px;
  color: brown;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-link {
  font-size: 14px;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Formulario de Login - Cliente</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_iniciar_sesion.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente.js"></script>
</head>

<body background="imagenes/fondo_campo2.jpg">
  <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
  <!--aqui coloco la imagen con sus estilos-->
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" style="height:32px; width:32px; top:0; left=0; padding-top:0;" >
    <h2>CLIENTE</h2>
    <h4>INICIAR SESIÓN</h4>
    <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1">
    <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2">
    <div id="mensaje" align="center">
      <?php if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'true'): ?>
      <h4>
        <p style="color:red;">¡Sus datos no son correctos!</p>
      </h4>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="iniciar" align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"><br/>
      <p class="form-link">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? <a href="registrar.php">Regístrate aquí</a></p><br/>
      <p class="form-link"><a href="recuperar_contrasena.php">He olvidado mi contraseña</a></p><br/>
      <hr/><br/>
      <p class="form-link"><img src="imagenes/entrar.jpg" height="10px" width="10px" alt="invitado" />&nbsp;<a href="reservar.php">Entrar como invitado</a></p>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Desde los estilos puedes traer la imagen así:

```
.idImagen {
   background-image: url("paper.gif");
   background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

y así puedes ponerla en la ezquina:

```
.idImagen {
   background-image: url("paper.gif");
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0; 
   left: 0;
}
```

y si trabajas con modelo de cajas es mas sencillo.
http://www.ite.educacion.es/formacion/materiales/182/cd/once/el_modelo_de_caja.html

Answer (score 2):

para hacerlo te puedes ayudar de los pseudoelementos **::before** o **::after**.

Simplemente **a #miformulario, le añadimos un position: relative** y luego agregamos el seudo así:

```
#miformulario::before{
  /*lo dejamos vacio, pero lo ponemos, es importante.*/
  content: ''; 
  /*para que se comporte como un div*/
  display: block; 
  /*O la medida que quieras para el icono*/
  width: 50px; height: 50px; 
  /*la imagen del icono*/
  background-image: url('imagen.png'); 
  /*Toma todo el ancho del pseudoelemento y 
  * automáticamente la altura por defecto de la imagen*/
  background-size: 100% auto; 
  /*para posicionarlo en donde queramos*/
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  /*para posicionarlo en la esquina superior izquierda*/
  /*Puedes cambiar left por right y top por bottom, 
  *depende de donde lo quieras poner*/
}
```

De esta manera si agregar o modificar el html, puedes agregar una imagen con solamente fines estéticos. Lo otro es que si la imagen ya está estará recortada al tamaño final, puedes desechar las propiedades **background-image y background-size** y **reemplazar la propiedad content: '';** que dejamos vacío antes y **añadirle la imagen de una vez: content: url('imagen.png')**;

Te dejo un ejemplo con tu mismo código. Los nuevos estilos están debajo de los tuyos.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 /*background: #DEDEDE;*/
 display: flex; /*Centrado en la página tanto vertical como horizontal.*/
 min-height: 100vh;
 /*background-size: cover;*/
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}

form{
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
 max-width: 500px;
 background: #F3F3F3;
 padding: 30px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}

h2{
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

h4{
 text-align: center;
}

input{
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 30px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
 background: linear-gradient(#FFDA63, #FFB940);
 border: 0;
 width: 160px;
 color: brown;
 opacity: 0.8;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-link{
 font-size: 14px;
}


a:hover  {
    color: red;
}

#miformulario{
  position: relative;
}

#miformulario::before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://resnickscity.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/firefox-habemus-icon.jpg');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Formulario de Login - Cliente</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_iniciar_sesion.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo2.jpg">
  <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
   <h2>CLIENTE</h2>
   <h4>INICIAR SESIÓN</h4>
   <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1">
   <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2">
   <div id="mensaje" align="center">
                <?php if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'true'): ?>
                    <h4><p style="color:red;">¡Sus datos no son correctos!</p></h4>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
   <div id="iniciar" align="center">
    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"><br/>
    <p class="form-link">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? <a href="registrar.php">Regístrate aquí</a></p><br/>
    <p class="form-link"><a href="recuperar_contrasena.php">He olvidado mi contraseña</a></p><br/><hr/><br/>
    <p class="form-link"><img src="imagenes/entrar.jpg" height="10px" width="10px" alt="invitado"/>&nbsp;<a href="reservar.php">Entrar como invitado</a></p>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```